# Can't see all methods with go pprof

Tags: go, pprof

I am using go pprof to profile my application, I have followed the next tutorial - 
http://saml.rilspace.org/profiling-and-creating-call-graphs-for-go-programs-with-go-tool-pprof

And my "--text" result of my profiling is -

> Total: 48 samples
>         48 100.0% 100.0%       48 100.0% runtime.mach_semaphore_wait
>          0   0.0% 100.0%       48 100.0% System

What should I do in order to get the full profiling result of the application?
(Generaly my application works with go-imap and json)

Answer (score 2):

`pprof` takes snapshots of your program at regular interval.  If some methods aren't currently on the stack when `pprof` takes the snapshot, they won't appear in the results.

Which means that your methods don't appear for very long on the stack - thus they aren't a bottleneck.  Or you don't run your profiling for long enough, so it doesn't produce enough samples.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is similar to https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6047

Alex